# Xlib: extension "XInputExtention" missing on display "localhost:1". Xubuntu Desktop on AWS

Tags: server, xubuntu

I have installed xubuntu and xfac4 on AWS using `vnc4server`. The desktop environment works fine in general. However, the strange thing is that when I run the software `paraview` from shell it works fine (even if slow), but when I run it from the Desktop environment I get the error:

```
Xlib: extension "XInputExtention" missing on display "localhost:1"
```

I have been looking around blogs and tutorials with no luck, can somebody help?

Thank you very much !!!